# How can I fix that a part of an UV image texture is not showing up on my model?

Tags: uv-image-editor

Part of my UV texture is not showing up on my model in both texture view and rendered view. As you can see here the text is not showing up.

[image: image with text]

I think the problem might be that I have another image open that is identical, but without the text, but I don't know how to switch which image it uses.

[image: image without text]

How can I fix that a part of an UV image texture is not showing up on my model?

Comment: don't use texture shading to assess the materials. Use material or rendered mode. Aslo it looks like you are using two different images as texture. Make sure you are using the correct one. Lastly if your issue is with materials used onthe object, include their settings in the image, the problem is clearly not in the world backgound we don't need to see that.

Comment: first off, you have to check your nodes in the Node Editor to see if the image chosen in the Image Texture is the one called "guitar neck.png", and not another one, then you need to make sure that you've assigned this material to this part of the mesh, and not another one

Comment: ok thanks a lot! I will keep this in mind.